# Has no member named, BST

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, binary-search-tree

I'm creating a binary tree and trying to print the names of a student object which im passing in. When I try to print the tree, I get an error:

> tree.h:181:46: error: ‘class samuel::Student’ has no member named ‘printInOrder’

`str += Node->get_data().printInOrder() + "\n";`

This is the function I'm calling in main using

`BSTree<Student>* student_tree = new BSTree<Student>;
Student student = Student("Adam");
student_tree->insert(student);
student_tree->printInOrder();`

```
string printInOrder(){return inOrder(root, 0);}

private:
  string inOrder(BTNode<value_type>* Node, size_t level)
  {
    string str ="";
    if(Node != NULL)
    {
      str += inOrder(Node->get_right(), level++);
      for(int i = 1; i <= level; ++i)
      {
        str = str + "| ";
      }
      str += Node->get_data().printInOrder() + "\n";
      str += inOrder(Node->get_left(), level++);
    }
    return str;
  }
```

I'm not sure why when I try to access printInOrder it goes through Student. This is my student class

```
typedef Student value_type;
Student::Student()
{

}

Student::Student(std::string init_name, float init_grade)
{
    name = init_name;
    std::string studentName[50]={"Adam", "Cameron", "Jackson", "KiSoon", "Nicholas", "Adrian", "Chris", "Jacob", "Lance", "Ryan", 
    "Alexander", "Damian", "James", "Liam", "Sang", "Andrew", "David", "Jared", "Madison", "Shane", "Ashley", "Dillon", 
    "Jodi", "Magdalena", "Simon", "Benjamin", "Dylan", "Jonathan",  "Marcus", "Thomas", "Bradley", "Ethan" "Joshua", "Mark", 
    "Timothy", "Brobie", "Frederik", "Julius", "Melanie", "Trent", "Callan", "Hong", "Kelly", "Min", "Troy", "Callum", "Hugh", "Kenias", "Mitchell", "Zaanif"};
    for (int i = 0; i <50; i++)
    { 
        int j = (rand() % (i-1));
        string temp = studentName[j];
        studentName[j] = studentName[i];
        studentName[i] = temp;
    }   
}
Student::~Student()
{

}
void Student::set_name(string new_name)
{
    name = new_name;
}

const string Student::get_name() const
{
    return name;
}

void Student::set_grade(float new_grade)
{
    grade = new_grade;
}

float Student::get_grade()
{
    return grade;
}
```

An alternative method I tried was using

```
string infix(BTNode<value_type>* Node)
{
  if (Node == NULL)
  {
    return "";
  }else{
    return (infix(Node->get_left()) + Node->get_data()) +
      infix(Node->get_right());
  }
}

friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const BSTree<value_type>& tree)
{
  out << tree.infix(tree.root) << endl;
  return out;
}
```

and then calling `cout << student_tree << endl` however this printed a memory address, would anyone also be able to clarify why that happens as well, thanks

Edit: Changed how I was inserting a student. Changed `cout << student_tree << endl`to `cout << *student_tree << endl`which gave the error

> tree.h:70:9: error: passing ‘const samuel::BSTree’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

```
out << tree.infix(tree.root) << endl;
```

Comment: Seems like `printInOrder` is part of the `BSTree` and not of each `Student`.

Comment: What is access modifier for printInOrder? By default it is private, so maybe you are not able to access this private method?

Comment: printInOrder is public, inOrder is private

Answer (score 1):

> tree.h:181:46: error: ‘class samuel::Student’ has no member named ‘printInOrder’

`Node->get_data()` returns object of `samuel::Student` type because of this compiler searches for `printInOrder()` in `samuel::Student` type. It's not there according to the code above. To fix the issue implement the method:

```
std::string Student::printInOrder()  
{
  // Return the data to be printed
}
```

> student_tree->insert(* new Student());

Looks suspicious. Tree contains `Student` objects by value. You create an `Student` object on the heap, dereference pointer and copies value into the Tree. Pointer lost after that. This will cause memory leak problem.

> cout << student_tree << endl however this printed a memory address

Because it's declared as `BSTree<Student>* student_tree`. It's a pointer to the tree, so the output is correct, you print the address. To print the tree value you need to dereference the pointer: `cout << *student_tree << endl`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I changed it to *student_tree, but now get the error tree.h:70:9: error: passing ‘const samuel::BSTree<samuel::Student>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
     out << tree.infix(tree.root) << endl;

Comment: @Riggy It's because you call non const `infix` method for `const samuel::BSTree<samuel::Student>`. Declare `infix` as `string infix(BTNode<value_type>* Node) const`

Comment: Doing this then made it so I need to overload the + operator for use in infix, but I know that I don't need to do this so something else must be an issue here.

Comment: @Riggy Why do you think you need to override `operator+` in `infix` method if `infix` is `const`?

Comment: Should have clarified, sorry

Comment: @Riggy Easy way to fix the problem, is to remove `const` at `const BSTree<value_type>& tree` argument in `operator<<`.

Comment: @Riggy But the proper way is to create proper `const` infix walk method.

Comment: thanks I'll give that a shot once I get my insert working

Answer (score 0):

continuation to other answer...

> and then calling cout << student_tree << endl however this printed a
>   memory address, would anyone also be able to clarify why that happens
>   as well, thanks

```
BSTree<Student>* student_tree = new BSTree<Student>;
```

`student_tree` is a pointer to `BSTree<Student>` it means it holds the memory location(a memory address) of BSTree object which is an unnamed object in this case.

you must dereference it to get the value inside the address by doing `*student_tree`

```
std::cout << *student_tree; // actual value, and will call operator<<
```